# Run local lambda using python 3.7

Tags: python, serverless-framework

I'm trying to run a local lambda function using the command `sls invoke local -f marketingAnalytics` but this throws me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/invoke.py", line 73, in <module>

    handler = getattr(module, args.handler_name)
AttributeError: module 'handler' has no attribute 'marketing_analytics'
```

Here is my handler.py (same level of file serverless.yml):

```
import marketing.analytics as a
import json

def marketing_analytics(event, context):
    a.consolidate_analytics()
    print('BLABLA')
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps({'message': 'success'})
    }
```

The import `marketing.analytics` refers to file `analytics.py` from module `marketing`.

This code is working on AWS.

I'm using Python 3.7.2. Is there something that should be configured to enable run locally?

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: Check the update. This code is working on AWS. The only problem is running locally

Comment: Is the marketing module used as a layer elsewhere on AWS?
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/

Comment: It's not. If I remove all imports and let a simple declaration like `def marketing_analytics(e, c): return 1` still getting the same error.

Comment: Looks like the commando `sls invoke local...` can't find this declaration `handler: handler.marketing_analytics` from serverless.yml

Comment: Fixed it: if i change file name from `handler.py` to something else, it works. I'll open a bug on serverless github.

Comment: Glad you got it  Quick question... is marketing module a folder with and `__init__.py` vs single file at `hander.py` level?  I was having the same issue

Comment: @placplacboom if you think your solution might be useful to someone else then add an answer.